# How to capture a portion of a version number stored in a variable in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, parsing

I am attempting to parse some data in a *bash* script and test the second part of a version number. Here is some example text, stored in a variable called `myinfo`:

```
Application 2021:

Version: 16.3.2.151
--
Application 2020:

Version: 15.1.3.302
```

I only need to capture the second part of the `2021` version that starts with `16` (`3` in this case) and test if it's 3 or greater.

I have tried many things from various answers around the web that seem related, without success.

For example, the closest I got was using the regex `(?:\b16\.)(\d)` works to find 16.3 on regexr but I hadn't figured out how to capture just the 3 (probably easy if I knew regex better).

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Paul Hodges for his concise answer. The background is I need to find the exact version of Adobe InDesign a user has on their system. 16.3 and above require different behavior in the remainder of the script. This could work for any situation where you needed to know an application's version number. Here is the final script, utilizing the solution I chose:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ask system_profiler for information about all the installed applications
#  then use fgrep to pull out the line, and the 2 lines after, that starts with Adobe InDesign 2021
v=$(system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType | fgrep -A 2 ' Adobe InDesign 2021')

echo ${v}
#    Adobe InDesign 2021:
#
#      Version: 16.3.2.151

# Strip everything up to the first .
v="${v#*.}"
# Strip everything after the first . of the remaining text
v="${v%%.*}"

echo "${v}"
# 3

# Test if it is greater or equal to 3
if [[ "${v}" -ge 3 ]]; then
    echo Its 3 or greater
else
    echo Less than 3
fi
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter parsing can do this in a couple steps without running a subprocess.

Assuming

```
x="Application 2021:

Version: 16.3.2.151
--
Application 2020:

Version: 15.1.3.302"
```

Then

```
x="${x#*.}"
```

strips everything from the front through the first dot, and

```
x="${x%%.*}"
```

strips everything from the (now) first dot to the end.

```
echo $x
3
```

So if your data is in `x`,

```
x="${x#*.}"; echo ${x%%.*}
```

will output `3`.

If you want more precise parsing, activate extended globbing.

```
$: shopt -s extglob
$: y="${x//*Application+([[:space:]])2021:+([[:space:]])Version:+([[:space:]])+([0-9])./}"
$: echo "${y%%.*}"
3
```

Just remember this is *globbing*, not real regex parsing.
For that, use `sed` or `awk`, though this will do the job just fine.

For more detailed info on globbing, c.f. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob
For more on basic parameter parsing, c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: this assumes the first `Application/Version` block is for `2021`; switch the ordering (ie, put the `2020` block first, or add a `2022` block first) ... or use the current variable definition but look for the `2020` value ... and we get the wrong value

Comment: Correct. Given the limited info provided, I opted for a simplistic approach. Given more detailed specs I might do it very differently.

Comment: The added section on extended globbing should handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there will only be one set of lines that match `Application 2021:` and `Version:`

Input variable:

```
$ typeset -p myinfo
declare -- myinfo="Application 2021:

Version: 16.3.2.151
--
Application 2020:

Version: 15.1.3.302"
```

One `sed` idea:

```
$ sed -En '/^Application 2021:/,/^Version:/ s/^Version: [^\.]*\.([^\.]+).*/\1/p' <<< "${myinfo}"
3
```

Where:

- `-En` - enable `E`xtended regex support; `n` => suppress default behavior of printing pattern space
- `'/^Application 2021:/,/^Version:/` - find range of lines where first line starts with `Application 2021:` and last line starts with `Version:` (literal period after the `16`)
- `s/^Version: [^\.]*\.` - for line (in the desired range of lines) that starts with `Version:`  + `<anything_not_a_period>` + `.` (literal period) ...
- `([^\.]+)` - first capture group is everything that is not a literal period
- `.*` - match rest of line
- `/\1/p` - print the first capture group

Capturing this value into a variable:

```
$ v=$(sed -En '/^Application 2021:/,/^Version:/ s/^Version: [^\.]*\.([^\.]+).*/\1/p' <<< "${myinfo}")
$ echo "${v}"
3
```

From here OP can do whatever is desired with the variable `${v}`, eg:

```
if [[ "${v}" -gt 3 ]]; then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
awk -F'[ :.]' '
  $1 == "Application" && $2 == 2021 {p = 1}
  p && $1 == "Version" {print $4; exit}
' <<<"$myinfo"
```